# Use Django Model to find 1 record per hour, and the most recent one from another timestamp

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

Django 3.2.9

db: (PostgreSQL) 14.0

**Model**

```py
class InventoryForecast(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField()
    forecast_for = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    forecasted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
```

**Data**

| id | count | forecast_for | forecasted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 40910 | 2022-10-10 11:00 | 2022-09-04 12:00 |
| 9 | 40909 | 2022-10-10 11:00 | 2022-09-05 12:00 |
| 10 | 50202 | 2022-10-10 11:00 | 2022-09-06 12:00 (most recent forecast) |
| 11 | 50301 | 2022-10-10 12:00 | 2022-09-04 12:00 |
| 12 | 50200 | 2022-10-10 12:00 | 2022-09-05 12:00 |
| 13 | 50309 | 2022-10-10 12:00 | 2022-09-06 12:00 (most recent forecast) |

How would I use Django Model to find 1 record per `forecast_for` hour, and the most recent one for the `forecasted_at` value? So in this example, 2 records.

**Desired results**

| id | count | forecast_for | forecasted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 50202 | 2022-10-10 11:00 | 2022-09-06 12:00 |
| 13 | 50309 | 2022-10-10 12:00 | 2022-09-06 12:00 |

**What I've tried**

```py
>>> from django.db.models.functions import TruncHour
>>> from django.db.models import Max
>>> 
InventoryForecast.objects.annotate(
    hour=TruncHour('forecast_for')
).values('hour').annotate(
    most_recent_forecasted_at=Max('forecasted_at')
).values('hour', 'most_recent_forecasted_at')

SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', "app_inventoryforecast"."forecast_for" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "hour",
       MAX("app_inventoryforecast"."forecasted_at") AS "most_recent_forecasted_at"
  FROM "app_inventoryforecast"
 GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', "app_inventoryforecast"."forecast_for" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
 LIMIT 21

Execution time: 0.000353s [Database: default]
<QuerySet [{'hour': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 10, 12, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'most_recent_forecasted_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 6, 11, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'hour': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 10
, 11, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'most_recent_forecasted_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 6, 11, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]>
```

That works correctly in the GROUP BY, but I need the `count` value. The trick is, when I add that into the `values` it changes my group by to return too many records.

```
>>>python
InventoryForecast.objects.annotate(hour=TruncHour('forecast_for')).values('hour').annotate(most_recent_forecasted_at=Max('forecasted_at')).values('hour', 'most_recent_forecasted_at', 'count', 'id').all().count(
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (
        SELECT "app_inventoryforecast"."count" AS Col1,
               "app_inventoryforecast"."id" AS Col2,
               DATE_TRUNC('hour', "app_inventoryforecast"."forecast_for" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS "hour",
               MAX("app_inventoryforecast"."forecasted_at") AS "most_recent_forecasted_at"
          FROM "app_inventoryforecast"
         GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', "app_inventoryforecast"."forecast_for" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
                  "app_inventoryforecast"."id"
       ) subquery

Execution time: 0.002036s [Database: default]
6
```

So that returns all the example rows, 6. I need to select all my columns and group by just the truncated hour, or similar and return the 2 recent forecasted rows.

Comment: Hour in date is always whole? No 11:30, 21:38 etc?

Comment: No, not in the database. That is why I was using [TruncHour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#timefield-truncation). Using that makes it whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution annotates new field `forecast_for_hour` which uses `TruncHour` to create whole hour from `forecast_for` timestamp, then orders by `forecast_for_hour` ascending and `forecasted_at` descending, grouping them. As it's PostgreSQL you are using, we can then call distinct on `forecast_for_hour` which, thanks to ordering by `forecasted_at` descending sort takes newest forecast

```
qs = (
        InventoryForecast.objects
        .annotate(forecast_for_hour=TruncHour('forecast_for'))
        .order_by('forecast_for_hour', '-forecasted_at')
        .distinct('forecast_for_hour')
    )
```

Comment: Great idea. Works well for me.